# I want to make a view control that is well really a times table test

Tags: ios

I've tried make an iphone app that displays two random numbers then you input an answer then press submit and it should display a label that says either Right or Wrong
but when I wrote the code it always displays Right
Here is the code:

```
 - (IBAction)but01Pressed:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"B111111");

    RandomNum = arc4random() %25;

    if (RandomNum == 0) {
        RandomNum = arc4random() %25;
        if (RandomNum == 0) {
            RandomNum = arc4random() %25;
        }
    }

    //@"GLOBAL=%@   %@",appd.globalString, name.text

    lab01.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    lab02.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    textF01.hidden = NO;
    textF02.hidden = NO;
    textF03.hidden = NO;
    adotime01.hidden = NO;
    equal01.hidden = NO;
    SubmitFQ01.hidden = NO;



    textF01.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",RandomNum];

    RandomNum = arc4random() %15;

    if (RandomNum == 0) {
        RandomNum = arc4random() %15;
        if (RandomNum == 0) {
            RandomNum = arc4random() %15;
        }
    }

    textF02.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",RandomNum];



}

 `enter code here`- (IBAction)submitbutPressed:(id)sender;
{
    if (textF03.text == [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[textF01.text intValue] * [textF02.text intValue]]) {
        label066.text = @"Wrong";
        label066.hidden = NO;
    }
else
    {
        label066.text = @"Right";
        label066.hidden = NO;
    }

        }
```

Comment: It looks like you have `RIGHT` and `WRONG` associated with the incorrect case in the last if statement...

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if (textF03.text == [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[textF01.text intValue] * [textF02.text intValue]]) {
```

should either be:

```
if ([textF03.text isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[textF01.text intValue] * [textF02.text intValue]]]) {
```

or better:

```
if ([textF03.text intValue] == [textF01.text intValue] * [textF02.text intValue]) {
```

You can't use `==` to compare two object values to see if the objects represent the same value.

And as mentioned in the comments, when the `if` statement is true, that is the "Right" answer, not the "Wrong" answer.

Side note:

Why this code:

```
RandomNum = arc4random() %25;

if (RandomNum == 0) {
    RandomNum = arc4random() %25;
    if (RandomNum == 0) {
        RandomNum = arc4random() %25;
    }
}
```

I'm guessing you actually want a random number in the range 1-24, correct? If so, simply do this:

```
randomNum = arc4random() % 24 + 1; // gives 1-24
```

Better yet, use:

```
randomNum = arc4random_uniform(24) + 1;
```

Make a similar change for your other value.

Comment: You're missing and end paren on `[textF03.text intValue`.